# Jquery/Javascript: Find cursor/focus field on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor-position

How do you capture the location of a cursor via an event listener?

In other words, if my user clicks a button, is it possible to find the location of the cursor at that time? If so, how?

**UPDATE**
I am not sure if I was clear enough. I don't want the *mouse* location. What I meant to say is that if a cursor is inside an input field on a form, I want to locate the cursor and find out where the FOCUS is.

Comment: If the user clicks something, I think the keyboard focus is removed from wherever it used to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, when you click on a button, the focus is gone from anywhere else it was. But I seem to understand you want to know where the focus was just before.

You could so something like:

```
$('input, textarea, select').on('focus', function() { 
  console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' just got focus!!');
  window.last_focus = $(this).
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  console.log('Last focus was on ' + window.last_focus.attr('id'));
});
```

This is just a very naive implementation. I am also very curious why you would need this?

There is also a `focusout` event which is triggered when something loses the focus, which might be more appropriate.

Comment: I have a form with buttons. When a user clicks the button, I was hoping to use the previously focused element as a reference point.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
  console.log(e.clientX)//relative screen
  console.log(e.clientY)
  console.log(e.pageX)//relative document(scroll + window position)
  console.log(e.pageY)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/eTsN3/

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
    alert(e.pageX + '/' + e.pageY);
});
```

Further details: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture mouse location with Jquery and store it inside some tag use :

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
     $('#sometag').html("X Axis : " + e.pageX + " Y Axis : " + e.pageY);

  });
```

The mouse location info is supported by `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`. So in your case you can use

```
$('button').click(function(e){
         $('#sometag').html("X Axis : " + e.pageX + " Y Axis : " + e.pageY);

      });
```

You can read [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which input field currently has the focus with:

```
$("input:focus")
```

However, this won't work when you click on a button, because clicking outside the input field blurs it before running the click handler for the clicked handler. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/QCpJC/6/) where I demonstrate it. It uses `preventDefault()`, but this doesn't prevent the blurring.